# IllegalArgumentException: PTBLexer: Invalid options key in constructor: asciiQuotes Stanford NLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, french

I'm trying to test the Hello word of [Stanford POS tagger](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) API in Java (I used the same .jar in python and it worked well) on french sentences.
Here is my code

```
public class TextPreprocessor {

    private static MaxentTagger tagger=new MaxentTagger("../stanford-tagger-4.1.0/stanford-postagger-full-2020-08-06/models/french-ud.tagger");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String taggedString = tagger.tagString("Salut à tous, je suis coincé");
        System.out.println(taggedString);
    }
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Loading POS tagger from C:/Users/_Nprime496_/Downloads/Compressed/stanford-tagger-4.1.0/stanford-postagger-full-2020-08-06/models/french-ud.tagger ... done [0.3 sec].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PTBLexer: Invalid options key in constructor: asciiQuotes
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer.<init>(PTBLexer.java)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer.<init>(PTBTokenizer.java:285)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer$PTBTokenizerFactory.getTokenizer(PTBTokenizer.java:698)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor$PlainTextIterator.<init>(DocumentPreprocessor.java:271)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor.iterator(DocumentPreprocessor.java:226)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(MaxentTagger.java:1148)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger$TaggerWrapper.apply(MaxentTagger.java:1332)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagString(MaxentTagger.java:999)
    at modules.generation.preprocessing.TextPreprocessor.main(TextPreprocessor.java:19)
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code and the full CoreNLP package:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;


public class PipelineExample {

  public static String text = "Paris est la capitale de la France.";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties("-props", "french");
    // set the list of annotators to run
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,mwt,pos");
    // build pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // create a document object
    CoreDocument document = pipeline.processToCoreDocument(text);
    // display tokens
    for (CoreLabel tok : document.tokens()) {
      System.out.println(String.format("%s\t%s", tok.word(), tok.tag()));
    }
  }

}
```

You can download CoreNLP here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Make sure to download the latest French models.

I am not sure why your example with the standalone tagger does not work. What jars were you using?

Comment: Thanks, I try it asap. I'm using stanford-pos-tagger-4.1.0.jar

Comment: I'd like to only use the tagger to avoid size issues. Oddly, tagTokenizedString() works

Comment: Actually you need to use the full CoreNLP because you need to use the mwt annotator for French (unless you can tokenize your text separately). The French part of speech model is expecting the multi word expansion done by the mwt annotator. If you are trying to limit RAM, you only need the French mwt resources and the French part of speech model. So the default CoreNLP models jar has a lot of stuff that you don't need. You can create a much smaller custom resources jar that fits your use case.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any help building a custom resources jar for your use case. Here is documentation about extracting and creating jar files: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html

Comment: We may consider creating a collection of small models jars for tasks like this...for instance we could make a French part of speech only jar, etc...

Comment: And just to summarize, I believe if you use full CoreNLP code plus just the models you need that is the same RAM footprint as using the standalone distribution.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is still a bug - the French tagger model hasn't been rebuilt since v4.0 and so still incorporates an old option name that no longer works. We'll update the models for the next release.